# Using Charcter().Insert to format pieces of text in a cell (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to insert a new line of text into an existing cell without losing the formatting.

In a single cell, I have a loop to add concatenated text based on a column in the sheet. This works fine, but I need to be able to format certain lines GREEN if it's additive and RED if it's removed when compared to a global standard.

For Example:

"Donald Duck 1 - Minnie Mouse  1

Donald Duck 2 - Minnie Mouse  2  (GREEN)

Donald Duck 3 - Minnie Mouse  3

Donald Duck 4 - Minnie Mouse  4 (RED)

Goofy - 39 - Pluto - 39

Goofy - 42 - Pluto - 42"

My current code does the loop, but the problem with this is that I lose the existing formatting every time I overwrite with a new data line in that cell.

```
If ActiveCell.Offset(0, ColumnOffset) = 1 Then

     Need = ActiveCell.Offset(NeedNameOffset, ColumnOffset).Value
     DocCode = ActiveCell.Offset(NeedNameOffset + 1, ColumnOffset).Value

         If NeedsType = "Data Needs" Then
            DestDataNeedsCell.Value = DestDataNeedsCell.Value & NeedsCategory & " - " & Need & vbCrLf

         ElseIf NeedsType = "Document Needs" Then
            DestDocNeedsCell.Value = DestDocNeedsCell.Value & NeedsCategory & " - " & Need & " (" & DocCode & ")" & vbCrLf

         End If
```

I tried using a Character().Insert function which seemed to work at first, but for some reason does not add in all of the data.  I also don't think my method of changing colors is properly changing just the active line.

```
If ActiveCell.Offset(0, ColumnOffset) = 1 Then

   strValue = ActiveCell.Offset(0, ColumnOffset).Value
   Need = ActiveCell.Offset(NeedNameOffset, ColumnOffset).Value
   DocCode = ActiveCell.Offset(NeedNameOffset + 1, ColumnOffset).Value

     If NeedsType = "Data Needs" Then
        If strValue = "+1" Then
           startChar = Len(DestDataNeedsCell)
           DestDataNeedsCell.Characters(Len(DestDataNeedsCell) + 1, 1).Insert (NeedsCategory & " - " & Need & vbCrLf)
           endChar = Len(DestDataNeedsCell)
           DestDataNeedsCell.Characters(Start:=startChar, Length:=endChar).Font.Color = vbGreen

        ElseIf strValue = "-1" Then
           startChar = Len(DestDataNeedsCell)
           DestDataNeedsCell.Characters(Len(DestDataNeedsCell) + 1, 1).Insert (NeedsCategory & " - " & Need & vbCrLf)
           endChar = Len(DestDataNeedsCell)
           DestDataNeedsCell.Characters(Start:=startChar, Length:=endChar).Font.Color = vbRed
        Else
           DestDataNeedsCell.Characters(Len(DestDataNeedsCell) + 1, 1).Insert (NeedsCategory & " - " & Need & vbCrLf)
     End If
```

Comment: Can you explain how your example relates to your code? If you want to preserve formatting you'll have to store the previous settings and then re-instate them after adding new text.

Comment: Apologies, the Disney characters were given to me as a redaction.

The data is structured in a grid of "Needs Categories" and specific "Needs" of data-sets and/or documents. Donald Duck 1 is a "Needs Category" and Minnie Mouse 1 is a more detailed "Need".

As the code loops through the grid, it finds a "1" which indicates that there is a need in that intersection. +1 and -1 are just comparisons of "child" categories to a "parent" standard.

For each need that it finds in the grid, it is adding the new line in the form of "Needs Category - Need" to the existing list

Comment: You say you are "adding concatenated text" - can you give an example of original text and final expected output - it's not clear from the example

Comment: The color coding is reference to that "child/parent" comparison to the standard.

Comment: Can you provide a plain English example - DIsney characters are fine!

Comment: Within a single cell, I start with ---
"Donald Duck 1 - Minnie Mouse 1
Donald Duck 2 - Minnie Mouse 2
Donald Duck 3 - Minnie Mouse 3" --- and need to add --- "Donald Duck 4 - Minnie Mouse 4"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this simple example will help. If you have the starting text as in your example in A1 and then "Donald Duck 4 - Minnie Mouse 4" in A5 this will add it to the end and colour the text red.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range, n As Long

n = Len(Range("A5")) 'new text added to end of A1

With Range("A1")
    .Characters(Len(.Value) + 1).Insert (vbCrLf & Range("A5"))
    .Characters(Len(.Value) - n, n + 1).Font.Color = vbRed
End With

End Sub
```